# Running an ES6 JS file from console

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app

In my Create-React-App I have a JS file that does some testing. This testing file imports modules from my app using ES6 import/export. These imported modules in turn import other modules. (Not node_modules but self written ones).

**What is the supposed way to run this test file from console?**

I can't simply run the file like this `node src/core/testing.js` because node does not support ES6-import and -export statements and even if I'd use `require` - the required file still uses `import` and I don't want to change that.

## some more context:

As far as I understand how CRA works with Babel and Webpack, the code needs to be "built" so that Babel transforms ES6 to commonJS and Webpack imports all dependencies. What I wrongly tried was just running the file as if it was a plain JS file. So, I must first "build" this test file with all the modules its imports and its dependencies before running it in the console. Is that correct? How would I do that?

Comment: [I searched your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=es6+run+module+from+console+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `{"type":"module"}` as `package.json` in that folder would do

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi doesnt work, i get this now: ```Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: ..src/<Path To Test File>.js```
@mplungjan I had tried this, getting error: ```Error: Not supported``` as Promise rejection of the import statement

Comment: you either `import` or `require` ... if any of your files uses `require` then `import` fails, and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes that's why in my test file I want to use ```import``` because the files I import also use ```import```. Please view the added context I just added to the Q.